# Sending a Json data from my html page to a php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I took a code from stackoverflow and created a "index.htm" page where it will also send a json data from html page to php here it is "test.php"

When I am trying to submit the data and seeing in web develop tool I am always getting this error:

> jquery.min.js:4 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/1701053/Desktop/ClientServer%20demo/test.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

 </head>
<body>

<form id="form" action="" method="post">
 Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
 Age: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
FavColor: <input type="text" name="favc"><br>
<input id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      // click on button submit
       $("#submit").on('click', function(){
          // send ajax
           $.ajax({
              url: 'test.php', // url where to submit the request
              type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
              dataType : 'json', // data type
              data : $("#form").serialize(), // post data || get data
              success : function(result) {
                  // you can see the result from the console
                  // tab of the developer tools
                  console.log(result);
              },
                 error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                  console.log(xhr, resp, text);
               }
             })
      });
   });

     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Test.php

```
<?php

   // this is just a test
    //send back to the ajax request the request

   echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Note: this is not my own work I am using it as a reference to understand how to actually send a Json object to server using javascript only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply we can say that `XMLHttpRequest()` not works when URL starts with `file:///`. Also `$.ajax()` function would no useful.

`XMLHttpRequest()` works with `http://` or `https://` URLs, So try to run this page from any [Web Server](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)